# Cascade a bunch of divs in Parent?

Tags: css

Is there a way to Cascade (not [this cascade](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/cascade-specificity-inheritance/), but position the divs inside its parent, see code below) with CSS?  I know you can using JS (especially using the function [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)), but can I do this in plain CSS?

I am trying to make the `.child` divs align themselves like pic below with the margin I give them, but it turns out like pic below.
[image: bad image]

I am trying to fix the gap specified in pic below.
[image]

The last picture at the far bottom (4th `.child` div) appears to align vertically with the second picture on the right (3rd `.child` div), how can I stop this with just CSS.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 40%;
}
.child img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://coolwildlife.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-1593/Brown%20Bear%20Picture%20001.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://xyer.co/wallpaper/6/3/nature-wallpaper-background-hd.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://xyer.co/wallpaper/6/3/nature-wallpaper-background-hd.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://xyer.co/wallpaper/6/3/nature-wallpaper-background-hd.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Cascade" in the sense of how you want your HTML elements to be positioned? any code to show us?

Comment: @MarcAudet sorry for the delay, I just added some code and pictures to explain.

Comment: How about using flexbox?

Comment: @j08691 I tried, but the issue with that is it works well with either 1 line or having all the images the same height.  using flex box it still creates large gaps but in different places than what I show above.

Comment: Are the dimensions of the images known or will they change?

Comment: @j08691 they will change.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward CSS-only approach to this kind of problem is to display the images vertically in columns and then display the columns horizontally:

```css
.parent {
position: absolute;
width: 1020px;
}

.column {
float: left;
width: 510px;
height: 100vh;
}

.child {
position: relative;
margin: 5px;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div class="column">
<div class="child"><img src="pic1" width="500px" height="500px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic2" width="500px" height="200px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic3" width="500px" height="200px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic4" width="500px" height="500px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic5" width="500px" height="200px"></div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="child"><img src="pic6" width="500px" height="200px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic7" width="500px" height="200px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic8" width="500px" height="200px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic9" width="500px" height="500px"></div>
<div class="child"><img src="pic10" width="500px" height="500px"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: this looks great, but I don't have a set height of the page (the page will show more and more images infinitely).  and i need the newest images to be at the top and the older images at the bottom.

Comment: I strongly suspect you will need a scripting language to achieve what you want. The technique above, using equal-width columns, is the only pure CSS approach I am aware of which will arrange regularly spaced elements of identical widths but non-identical heights.